# How can I generate a secure random number in an Azure Worker Role?

Tags: c#, azure, random, cryptography, azure-worker-roles

I know to use the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, but is there anything special that I need to do to ensure that it's not using the same seed each time (such as at start-up)? Do I need to pull some data from outside sources on initialization? Or does the system do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great Microsoft documentation, could not find anything about the algorithm or the seeding.

[Wikipedia to the rescue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom):

> Windows developers have several alternative means of accessing the CryptGenRandom functionality; these alternatives invoke the same algorithm and share the same security characteristics, but may have other advantages.

...

> [Using RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom#Using_RNGCryptoServiceProvider)
>
> Programmers using .NET should use the RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class

Note that Wikipedia seems outdated, for more up to date information, check [the Microsoft pages of the CryptGenRandom function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

Note that this answer is only valid if you actually get the Microsoft CSP that uses the `CryptGenRandom` function. If you are on a non-Windows platform, or if you are refering to a different CSP, then check out those specific runtime configurations.

Comment: And I guess that's as conclusive as it gets from our friends of Mickeysoft. I haven't seen a fully specified crypto API from them yet.

Comment: I'll see if I can't get a response back from someone on the Azure team. Thanks for the answer! I'll include it in my query.